# Encontrar anagrama en un archivo de texto en python

Tags: python

Estoy astacado en una tarea, en la tarea nececito crear una funcion que en esa funcion busca en un archivo de texto una cantidad x de letras anagramas, luego de haberlas encontrado cada par se guardara como `tuple` y la función devolvera el `tuple`

> ejemplo:
>
> ***`> find_anagrams(1000) [('abel', 'able'), ('aboard', 'abroad'), ('abode', 'adobe'), ('accrues', 'accuser')]`***

este es mi código:

```
n=int(input("Enter a number:"))

def find_anagrams(n):
    t=0
    file = open("words.txt")
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):

            if (file.readline(i).lower().sort()==file.readline(i+1).lower().sort()):
                t[i]=(file.readline(i).lower().sort(),file.readline(i+1).lower().sort())

    return t

print(find_anagrams(n))
```

Comment: Hola, has definido `t` como un entero, no creo que `t[i]` te esté funcionando, estás tratando de setear el índice en un entero y eso es un error. Por otro lado, el sorting normalmente es una operación costosa, ¿qué tal si en vez de ordernarlos y compararlos simplemente sumas la representación de cada caracter usando `ord()`? Si la suma es igual entonces es un anagrama.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero una pregunta, como  creo entonces un tuple?

Comment: ¿Tienes el ejemplo del archivo? No me queda clara esa parte

Comment: Aarhus
Aaron
Ababa
aback
abaft
abandon
abandoned
abandoning
abandonment
abandons
abase
abased
abasement
abasements

Comment: ¿Se supone que hay una palabra por línea de texto?

Comment: si, cada palabra se encuentra en una linea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es leer el fichero de palabras. Lo más cómodo es leerlo en memoria. Trabajar directamente sobre el fichero, como pretendes, no es muy aconsejable (además de que `file.readline(i)` no funciona como lo estás usando. El parámetro `i` no indica la línea a leer, sino la cantidad de bytes a leer como máximo).

Creamos un iterador `lines` con todas la líneas del fichero y quitamos el salto de línea del final (`x[:-1]`). Limitamos este iterador a las `n` primeras líneas con la función `itertools.islice` y obtenemos una lista. Todo dentro de un bloque `with` para asegurar que el fichero se cierre una vez obtenido la lista:

```
from itertools import islice

with open("words.txt") as file:
    lines = (x[:-1].lower() for x in file.readlines())
    words = list(islice(lines, n))
```

Ahora que tenemos la lista de palabras, tenemos que pensar cómo hacemos las comparaciones. Podemos intentar comparar palabras, todas contra todas, pero tiene un coste muy alto, *O(n^2)*, por lo que tardaría mucho si las listas son muy largas. Hay que probar algún tipo de estrategia que mejore los resultados.

Algo habitual es crear un diccionario que nos clasifique las palabras candidatas a ser anagrama, de modo que podamos limitar el número de comparaciones. Por ejemplo, podríamos organizar las palabras por longitud y sólo comparar las palabras con igual longitud. También podríamos crear el diccionario usando la palabra ordenada como clave (algo parecido a lo que empezaba a hacer tu código). Incluso podemos hacer como sugería @César y usar la suma de los códigos de todas las letras como clave.

Por simplificar, voy a usar como clave del diccionario la palabra con las letras ordenadas:

```
def key(word):
    return "".join(sorted(word))

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for w in words:
    d[key(w)].append(w)
```

Se podía haber usado un diccionario normal en lugar de `defaultdict`, pero de este modo se simplifica el código y empieza a ser habitual ver su uso de esta manera.

En este momento, tenemos un diccionario con todos los anagramas agrupados por la misma clave. Para extraer las tuplas, basta con fijarnos en los items del diccionario que tenga dos elementos:

```
anagrams = [tuple(v) for v in d.values() if len(v) == 2]
```

La pega es que podría haber más de dos anagramas para la misma clave. Por ejemplo:

```
"aab": ["aab","aba","baa"]
```

Aunque no se explicita en el enunciado, podemos pensar que, en estos casos, se deberían sacar todas las combinaciones posibles, o sea, algo así:

```
("aab", "aba")
("aab", "baa")
("aba", "baa")
```

Para este cometido nos va muy bien `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

anagrams = [tuple(r) for v in d.values() for r in combinations(v, 2)]
```

Y con esto hemos acabado. El código completo quedaría:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations


def key(w):
  return "".join(sorted(w))

d = defaultdict(list)
for w in words:
    d[key(w)].append(w)

anagrams = [tuple(r) for v in d.values() for r in combinations(v, 2)]
```

---

**Editado**: añadida la función `key`. Se requiere un objeto *hashable* como índice de diccionario.

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, solamente hay una cosa que no entiendo, que es lo que hace este codigo:                                               
                                                                                                                 
 'from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for w in words:
    d[sorted(w)].append(w)'

Comment: Con `sorted(w)` como *clave*, podemos identificar anagramas como *las palabras con la misma clave*. Para agrupar elementos según una clave, ya es habitual usar un *"modismo"* (*"idiom"*) que incluso viene en la [documentación de defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples). Con `defaultdict(list)` se crea un diccionario cuyos elementos tienen por defecto el valor `list()` (*lista vacía*) de modo que `d[sorted(w)].append(w)` funcione siempre, incluso cuando se añade el primer elemento que se añadiría a una lista vacía.

Comment: ahora el problema es que cuando esta corriendo :d[sorted(w)].append(w)el program se termina con este error : line 14, in find_anagrams
    d[sorted(w)].append(w)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Más no puedo decirte sin conocer con qué datos lo estás probando. Seguramente tengas una línea en blanco en el fichero o el fichero este vacío.

Comment: no tengo linea en blanco en el fichero y tampoco el fichero esta vacio, la funcion me lee los datos pero no lo mete a la lista nueva "d".

Comment: OK. Ya he cambiado el código. Como clave de diccionario se requiere un objeto *hashable*, cosa que una lista mutable no lo es. He añadido un función key que convierte la lista en una string, que es lo que emplea como clave.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya me trabaja.